# Smoke simulation not showing up in render when rendering animation

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

[image: Smoke domain material][image: Smoke domain settings]I'm trying to render a scene that has a smoke simulation in it. It shows in every view and when rendering individual frames. But when I try to render an animation, it's just missing. The domain has a material and everything ia correct except the animation rendering.

Comment: Sorry, just from saying everything is correct it is really hard to determine where the issue lies. You should at the very least show some settings of the domain, flow object and smoke material for example. But even then, smoke simulations can be quite tricky with many things to care for, so it would probably be best to upload your file to https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question.

Comment: It was too big for blend exchange so I uploaded it to dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/y21ynnd3aksqcairjdmyh/time.blend?rlkey=0k2p17won1oqi5nx1qllcrifp&dl=0

Comment: Just a tip for the next time: you don't need to upload a complete scene if there is a problem with the smoke simulation. Delete everything except for the domain, the flow object and the effector objects and save it as a new file. This way it's only 10 MB instead of 107 MB. Regarding your problem: I could render the smoke. However, your domain _Cache_ > _Type_ is set to _Replay_, which means whenever you are doing something in your scene it might be recalculated and then the smoke information is lost and cannot be rendered. Set it to _All_ and bake the simulation before rendering.